# Using Ajax to POST JSON object in rails, and save it to a database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, post

I've looked through a number of these types of problems, but i can't quite figure it out.I'm really new to ruby on rails. I'm creating an application in rails that administers a printer. Basically what I'm trying to do here is POST a json object using ajax from the frontend which is written in javascript to the backend which I'm writing in rails. Basically what happens is when a user decides to checkout and print something, the json object is sent to the server and a new rails object is created using the json object's data. I want to create a rails object containing the data from the json object.

My ajax, located in the frontend javascript. Note that this code is in a completely seperate application:

```
     $.ajax({
                beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                    toggleModal();
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "OAuth "+auth_header);
                },
                url:message.action,
                async:true,
                type:message.method,
                dataType:'json',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(userSession),
                error: function(data){
                    toggleModal();
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#page_thankyou"),{ transition: "slide"});
                },
                success: function(data){
                    toggleModal();
                    console.log(userSession);
                    $.mobile.changePage($("#page_thankyou"),{ transition: "slide"});
                }
            })  


Here is the userSession Object:



userSession = {
                "kiosk_session":{
                    "session_id":"",
                    "is_order":"",
                    "session_items":[]
                }
            };

    In my Kiosk_session controller:

              # POST /kiosk_sessions.json
      def create
        puts YAML::dump params
        @kiosk_session = KioskSession.new(params[:kiosk_session])
        respond_to do |format|
          if @kiosk_session.save
            format.html { redirect_to @kiosk_session, notice: 'Kiosk session was successfully created.' }
            format.json { render json: @kiosk_session, status: :created, location: @kiosk_session }
          else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @kiosk_session.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

and my kiosk_session model:

```
  class KioskSession < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessible :id, :is_order, :is_reprint, :reprint_reason, :price,
      :paid, :printed, :print_date, :session_items_attributes, :kiosk_id

  has_many :session_items
  has_one :kiosk_kiosk_session
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :kiosk

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :session_items

  before_save :before_save_callback

  def before_save_callback
    new_KSS = KioskKioskSession.new(:kiosk_id => self.kiosk_id, :kiosk_session_id => self.id)
    new_KSS.save
    self.total_price
  end

  def total_price
    #session_items.to_a.sum {|item| session_items.total_price}
    #array to hold subtotals
    price = 0.00
    #finds each item in session
    session_items = SessionItem.where(:kiosk_session_id => self.id)
    #creates array of subtotals
    session_items.each do |t|
        #if t.price
      t.set_price
        price += t.price
    end
    self.price = price
  end

end
```

oh and my POST route for creating a kiosk session is /kiosk_session#create

I know this code is a mess, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? All you've posted is (as far as we know) a working application.

Comment: My question is, how do I get that json object from the javascript? My controller just has format.json, is that all the ruby I need to receive the data from the object?

Comment: Whatever JSON you've submitted is in `params`.

Comment: Thanks! so params will hold the json object? or will it already be parsed. sorry, I'm only one month into rails.

Comment: It will already be parsed. Check out your Rails console, you should see the value of `params` there.

Comment: Great, literally spent a full day trying to figure out something I already had accomplished. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Err, by "Rails console" I meant your Rails logs.